# About rvalues' scope and memory leaks

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, rvalue

What happens with rvalues if you stay in the same block "forever"?

Suppose I have the following code:

```
char buff[999];
time_t timer;
while(true){
...
    time(&timer);
    strcpy(buff, ctime(&timer));
...
}
```

In each iteration an rvalue `char *` will return from `ctime`, but will it be disposed by the end of the iteration or will it be disposed only when the block is done?

If it's only when the block is done, then after a few millions of iterations, the memory could be filled with finished rvalue `char*` right?

(I tagged this with `c` and `c++` because I also want to know if there's a difference regarding this between the two)

Comment: To my knowledge it creates a temporary object whose scope is up to the terminating semicolon i.e the scope of what ever is returned from ctime(&timer) is at the semicolon(;) of that statement, unless what it returns is created on the heap in that case you are responsible for freeing it.

Comment: Read the man page of `ctime`: The four functions asctime(), ctime(), gmtime() and localtime() return a pointer to static data and hence are  not  thread-safe.

Comment: You don't stay in the same block forever, each iteration creates a new block. But this has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Why being thread safe is relevant to memory leaks? @DieterLücking

Comment: @kuhaku I was just copying an entire line.

Comment: @FrankPuffer so there's no chance that rvalues remain around after an iteration is done, even if they don't die by the semicolon of the statement?

Comment: @kuhaku Lifetime of the raw pointer is not relevant either, is it? Rather the thing it points to. The returned pointer is an rvalue, but it does not point to an rvalue (it can't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer returned by `ctime` is called a *value*, in both C and C++. It is not an object, therefore it does not have a lifetime or storage duration.

Your question is like asking: In the code `for(;;) { 10 + 10; }` will the memory get filled up with `20`?  (with the answer being: No).

(Not to be confused with *temporaries* in C++, which are objects and do have lifetimes).

In C, the return value of a function may be accessed up until the end of the current statement (i.e. the next `;` in your case), although for a scalar type this is not relevant because there is no syntax that would express such an access . This provision refers to something like `printf("%d\n", foo().x);`, where `foo()` returns a struct by value.

The code `printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n, foo().x, foo().x, foo().x, foo().x, foo().x, foo().x, foo().x, foo().x, foo().x, foo().x);` does require the compiler to implement 10 return value objects but they all die at the `;` .

NB. Your question contains an inherent misconception. The block ends when `}` is reached, even if there is another iteration. The next iteration is a new block and variables declared inside the block are conceptually destroyed and re-created each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

For historical reasons, functions in the C libraries return different classes of memory:

- Statically allocated memory that doesn't need to be freed. The library typically declares that as static array in its code and will re-use the very same area of memory on every function call. `ctime`and `localtime` are examples for this. Do **not** free this memory. (It might be worth mentioning those functions are considered deprecated and kind of dying out as they are not suitable for multi-threaded operations)
- Dynamically allocated memory that *needs* to be freed by the caller. This memory is dynamically allocated by the library function that allocates that memory using `malloc()`, hands a pointer back to you and expects you to `free()` that memory once you are done with it. `strdup()` would be a good example for this form.

You simply *need to know* what class the specific library call you are using will return in order to know whether you are expected to `free()` that memory or not. Consult the man page for the respective call.

The iteration through your loop does absolutely not matter in the case of `ctime()`. As the library returns *the very same buffer address* on each iteration, which is written to the *very same place in the stack frame* there is no such thing as a memory leak. If you would call `strdup()` instead in your loop, you would be creating a memory leak.

Comment: I think he is asking about the pointer returned by `ctime` (not the space to which that pointer points)

Comment: The pointer returned is just a pointer, and an `auto` variable that occupies the same space on every iteration of the loop - What issues could there be with it?

Answer (score 1):

(I'm talking about C here, for C++ this is much more complex)

Local variables such as your

```
char buff[999];
time_t timer;
```

...are typically allocated all together when the function is entered. Such variables are either allocated space in the stack frame (in the case of buff) or directly on the hardware registers (probable in the case of timer).

All these allocations are done together in one machine instruction just by moving the pointer to the top of the stack. There is only one instance of each local variable per function call so **there is no danger of memory filling up because you use them in loops**. Furthermore there will be a comparatively low global limit on how large this area of memory can grow (on the order of 10 megabytes).

All local variables are automatically disposed when the function exits by destroying the stack frame. Again this is done just by moving the stack pointer back again. This is in contrast to static function variables (which are just global variables with limited reachability) and dynamically allocated (heap) variables which must be explicitly allocated or free'd.

Stack frames are a bit too complex to cover in full here but I recommend you to read up on them since understanding how function calls work really helps in the general understanding of C programming.

If you have any more specific question about variable storage I'm sure you can find help here on stack overflow since most of us C programmers enjoy talking about this sort of thing :)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, which is about the return value of `ctime`

Comment: @M.M I think ctime() was mostly used as an example and the question was of a more general nature. But perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: I asked in general about rvalues, `ctime` was just an example. @M.M

Comment: Your answer only seems to talk about local variables or static variables  , it's hard to see how "rvalues" refers to that

Comment: rvalues exist in the standard, not in reality. OP's question as I read it was really about how local variables work, how they are allocated and disposed. With respect to OP, it's not obvious that he understands exactly what "rvalue" means yet and is using it in a correct formal context. I think it's likely he meant just "value" in general.